# Cannot breakout of foreach loop in scala

Tags: scala, gatling

i have this below code

```
> .foreach("${plist}", "newshole") {
>        exec(
>          http("get the user id")
>            .get("${newshole}/jcr:content.1.json")
>            .headers(headers_2)
>            .check(bodyString.saveAs("Res1"))
>        )
>        exec(session => {
>          var mynewshole = session("Res1").as[String]
>          if (!mynewshole.contains("testingInProgress")) {
>            println("Doesn't contain: " + mynewshole)
>            (http("post the user id")
>              .post("${newshole}/jcr:content")
>              .headers(headers_2)
>              .formParam("testingInProgress", session.userId))
>            exec(http("Create print package")
>              .post("/bin/cqtg-create-print-package.do")
>              .headers(headers_2)
>              .formParam("newsholeId", "${plist}")
>              .formParam("digitalMasterId", "1adpy8")
>              .check(status.is(200)))
> 
>          }
>          session
>        })   
>      }
```

i want to break out of :

```
> if (!mynewshole.contains("testingInProgress")) {
>            println("Doesn't contain: " + mynewshole)
>            (http("post the user id")
>              .post("${newshole}/jcr:content")
>              .headers(headers_2)
>              .formParam("testingInProgress", session.userId))
>            exec(http("Create print package")
>              .post("/bin/cqtg-create-print-package.do")
>              .headers(headers_2)
>              .formParam("newsholeId", "${plist}")
>              .formParam("digitalMasterId", "1adpy8")
>              .check(status.is(200)))
> 
>          }
>          session
```

basically i want break out from the loop when my first condition meet.So i want to use the below code as per scala tutorials but don't know where to put the breakable command as it is giving me errors.

```
> breakable{
>             code ()
>          break;
>            }
```

but don't know where to put it.Any Idea????

Comment: you may want to consider **recursion** since you are using Scala :-)

Comment: basically i simply want to break out of the loop as scala donot have break or continue explicitly defined.Sorry bit new in scala need help !!! :(

Comment: This looks like Gatling DSL, right? As there are descriptions of requests to run, I'm not sure you'll be ever able to break out of the foreach. Maybe worth reading Gatling documentation on how to handle such scenario if ever possible.

Answer (score 4):

Scala doesn't really offer any easy-to-use `break`/`continue` control flow primitives.  It's not the functional way of doing things.

Most of the methods available on Scala collections, like `foreach`, are designed to inspect/modify the entire collection.  The exceptions include: `contains`, `corresponds`, `exists`, `forall`, `indexWhere`, etc.  You'll note that most (all?) deal with Booleans, either as an argument (a predicate function) or as the return type.

If your algorithm can't be reworked to utilize one of these lazy-evaluated methods then I'd recommend following @pietro909's advice and redesign it as a recursive function which tests for one or more exit conditions on every invocation/recursion.

I know that isn't really what you asked for, and it's true you can achieve what you want by inserting a `breakable` block in your code, but if you [inspect the source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/util/control/Breaks.scala#L1) you'll see that the breaks are implemented by throwing/catching exceptions, which is pretty inefficient and usually worth avoiding.

But if you're determined to go down that road, this should provide some guidance:

```
scala> import util.control.Breaks
import util.control.Breaks

scala> val mybreaks = new Breaks
mybreaks: scala.util.control.Breaks = scala.util.control.Breaks@69ea3742

scala> import mybreaks.{break, breakable}
import mybreaks.{break, breakable}

scala> breakable {
     | (1 to 34).foreach(x => if (x > 9) break else println(x))
     | println("all done")
     | }
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Note: The `break` doesn't just terminate the `foreach()` statement, it breaks out of the entire `breakable` block.

Comment: what happens if I dont use a breakable block. In other words what is the significance of the breakable block?

Comment: `break` throws an exception. `breakable` defines where the exception is caught and program execution continues.